# How delete duplicates rows with original?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

How can I delete duplicate row with original row, where is `unique_id` same ?

Table is:

```
unique_id  col1   col2   col3
95         1       1      1
21         1       1      1
23         1       1      1
29         1       1      1
95         2       1      2
```

I want delete both rows, where `unique_id` is same. A tried a few queries, but I didn't get me to delete both lines. Mostly I managed only the duplicate.

Comment: *"A tried a few queries, but I didn't get me to delete both lines"* Then show us those attempts. We can't explain why they didn't work if you don't show us said attempt(s).

Comment: *where is unique_id same* How can a **unique**_id be twice in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions and a CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, count(*) over (partition by unique_id) as cnt
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt >= 2;
```

If you wanted to keep one of them, you would use `row_number()` instead:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by unique_id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
delete from t
where unique_id in (
  select unique_id from t group by unique_id having count(*) > 1
)
```